# Networking related

Tags: windows, switch

I created two Vlans in a switch:  Vlan 2 and 4.  I want to access these two vlans in my computer without help of L3 switches. For this purpose I created port 24 as a trunk and directly connected to it to my pc, but am not able to access this two vlans.

Please tell how to solve this problem.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Usually there is a utility that comes with your nic drivers or from your nic manufacturer.  This utility should allow you to setup two virtual interfaces from your one physical dot1q trunk.